# Show that $\mathbb R$ is countably compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness

> Show that $\mathbb R$ is countably compact, that is that any cover has an at most countable subcover.

I tried to use the fact that every open set in R is a union of intervals with rational endpoints.

I tried to use the below fact first.
[If every open subset of $\mathbb R$ is a disjoint union of open intervals, the number of the intervals is at most countable] 
but I realized that this is just a special case, 
and what I need to prove is that "any" cover has at most countable subcovers.

Could you help me please?

Thank you!

Comment: Cover the compact intervals $[-n,n]$. Each can be covered by finitely many elements of the cover of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Note: That's not "countably compact" ($\mathbb{R}$ isn't), that's "Lindelöf". Countably compact means that every countable cover has a finite subcover.

Comment: In that case take the intervals $(-n,n)$ to show that it is not.

Comment: If you allow "any cover", consider the cover by singletons $\{a\}$, one for each $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Its only subcover is itself, and that's not countable.

Comment: You can also use the fact that $\mathbb R$ is separable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To repeat what was noted in the comments, you’re not showing that $\Bbb R$ is countably compact: you’re showing that it’s *Lindelöf*. The difference between the two properties lies largely in the placement of the word *countable*:

> A space $X$ is *countably compact* if every countable open cover of $X$ has a finite subcover. It’s *Lindelöf* if every open cover of $X$ has a countable subcover.

Your idea of using the fact that every open set in $\Bbb R$ is a union of open intervals with rational endpoints is a good one. It works: you just have to fill in some details. Let $\mathscr{B}$ be the set of open intervals with rational endpoints, and let $\mathscr{U}$ be any open cover of $\Bbb R$. For each $x\in\Bbb R$ choose a $U_x\in\mathscr{U}$ and a $B_x\in\mathscr{B}$ such that $x\in B_x\subseteq U_x$. (How do you know that this is possible?) Now let $\mathscr{B}_0=\{B_x:x\in\Bbb R\}$.

1. Explain why $\mathscr{B}_0$ is a countable open cover of $X$.
2. For each $B\in\mathscr{B}_0$ there is a $U_B\in\mathscr{U}$ such that $B\subseteq U_B$; why?
3. Show that $\{U_B:B\in\mathscr{B}\}$ is a countable subfamily of $\mathscr{U}$ that covers $\Bbb R$.
4. Since $\mathscr{U}$ was an arbitrary open cover of $\Bbb R$, conclude that $\Bbb R$ is Lindelöf.